# Laravel validation date field before:another_date_field plus some period

Tags: laravel

I have Laravel 5.5 project. In my_table I have 2 date fields: "valid_since" and "valid_to". I need "valid_to" field was after ("valid_to" + 5 year).

I have tried:

```
'valid_to' => 'required|date|after:valid_since',
```

Also I have tried:

```
'valid_to' => 'required|date|after:+5 year',
```

This two cases was working, but not the way I want. I need something like:

```
'valid_to' => 'required|date|after:valid_since +5 year',
```

But third case doesn't work. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
'valid_to' => ['required','date','after:'.Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', \Request::input('valid_since'))->addYear(5)]
```

The above approach will do what you want.

Basically in your validation for `after` the specific date, you will use the requested field valid_since (like you thought of) but you are going to use `Carbon` to actually add 5 years to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
'valid_to' => 'required|date|after:'.Carbon::create($request->valid_since)->add(5, 'year')->toDateString(),
```

Don't forge to import carbon in the controller

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. At the end you need to add:

->toDateString();

Comment: Please consider upvoting and accept answer if it is useful